# Stargazer not publishing regression table

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

The packages I currently have downloaded are: tinytex, stargazer, and rmarkdown.

I have used this function to create a publishable table:

```
stargazer(EB734_May_2010_model_u)
```

But got this instead:

```
% Table created by stargazer v.5.2.2 by Marek Hlavac, Harvard University. E-mail: hlavac at fas.harvard.edu
% Date and time: Wed, Sep 02, 2020 - 09:30:46
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\\[-1.8ex] & trust \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 D\_economy2 & $-$0.220$^{*}$ \\ 
  & (0.119) \\ 
  & \\ 
 D\_economy0 & 0.243$^{**}$ \\ 
  & (0.118) \\ 
  & \\ 
 E\_economy2 & $-$0.166 \\ 
  & (0.112) \\ 
  & \\ 
 E\_economy0 & $-$0.168 \\ 
  & (0.112) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Support\_EMU0 & 0.655$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.027) \\ 
  & \\
 Constant & $-$2.038$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.148) \\ 
  & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 18,282 \\ 
Log Likelihood & $-$22,543.580 \\ 
Akaike Inf. Crit. & 45,141.170 \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

I need to publish the summary for my logistic regression model into word from R.

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks. :)

Comment: Open `help(stargazer, stargazer)` and read `type` argument.

Comment: Obligatory note that you shouldn’t use ‘stargazer’, because [‘stargazer’ is an utterly atrocious package](https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/6o9v9h/whats_your_favorite_relatively_obscure_r_package/dkgw9q1/). Use ‘texreg’ instead, or literally *anything* else.

Comment: @KonradRudolph - 'texreg' is quite unaesthetic - would you recommend anything else?

Comment: @AnriSakakibara I don’t understand what you mean: the *opposite* is the case — ‘texreg’ applies proper table formatting. It’s ‘stargazer’ that completely screws it up. If you want to customise how the resulting table should look like you can do this via a LaTeX preamble … but in general you shouldn’t fiddle too much, since the output from ‘texreg’ already conforms to established typographic convention (whereas ‘stargazer’ does absolutely everything to break them).

Comment: I would also look into the `gtsummary` package for reporting regression output to word. Have you used this before @KonradRudolph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be:

```
stargazer(EB734_May_2010_model_u, type = "text")
```

which will give you output in text form that you can use immediately.

Alternatively, if you want a good-looking HTML table that you can then paste into Word:

```
stargazer(EB734_May_2010_model_u, out = "output.html")
```

Don't worry if your Rmd shows a lot of code below as output, just go into your working directory after you run it, and look for a file called "output.html". You should be able to open that with Word, and then copy and paste into your document.